# error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'long int')

Tags: c, stack

I need to read the contents of the stack after executing a function

since I know the highest and lowest address on the stack, I tried to read the contents of the stack
I creat this function into the code

```
int pile_start =0xd0000890;
int size =0x1890;

void read_stack()

ptrdiff_t i;
    for ( i = pile_start; i < size; i++)        {
        printf("pile = %d", *(pile_start+i));     // error
    }
```

but I had this error :

```
 error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'long int')
```

can be the way how I read the contents of the stack is not correct
I need your help please

Comment: What line is the error on? And please indent and format your code properly

Comment: What should be the type of  `*(pile_start+i)` per your understanding? What should it evaluate to?

Comment: Please apply proper indentation to your code. It's hard to read where functions start of end.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear enough. You are trying to apply the indirection operator to an object of the type long int

```
printf("pile = %d", *(pile_start+i));
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Maybe you mean just

```
printf("pile = %ld", (pile_start+i));
```

Or you need to cast the variable `pile_start` to a pointer as for example

```
printf("pile = %d", *( unsigned char * )(pile_start+i));
```

Comment: OK, but now when runs, does not display stack contents

Comment: @Rbn If the stack grows from down to up then maybe you need to write *( unsigned char * )(pile_start - i)

Comment: ok thanks bcp
now display the contents of the stack : 
pile = 136 
pile = 33 
pile = 132 
pile = 197 
pile = 15 
pile = 16 
pile = 0 
pile = 191 
pile = 25 
pile = 64 
pile = 0 
pile = 116 
pile = 216 
pile = 139 
pile = 25 .....
I have the impression that it is not logical that these valeu

Answer (score 0):

```
printf("pile = %d", *(pile_start+i));
```

Here `pile_start` is a a number - an `int`, I am assuming `i` is a number as well as you are using it as index in `for` loop. `(pile_start+1)` results in datatype `int` and value at `int` is invalid.

To use "*", you need to have a pointer. So first convert `(pile_start+1)` to pointer and then read value at that location.

If you change your code to

```
printf("pile = %d", *(uint32_t*)(pile_start+i));
```

It should show contents at that address.

Comment: I had: pile = -2078177253 ,it does not make sense

Comment: @Rbn Why not? What would you expect? The hex number you assign is negative if you print as signed integer.

Comment: I am waiting to read the contents of the stack between Lowest: 0xd0000898
Highest: 0xd0001898